# How to parse Excel's cell string with regexp in VBA macro

Tags: regex, string, vba, excel

I'm writing a macro in Excel 2010 in order to remove line breaks in multiple cells of a column.
Actually, I have 5 cases for which I have to search within the cells.
I enumerate them as follows:

1. If there's a dot or a comma followed by a blank space and then a newline(\n), replace it with dot or comma( whatever it had before regexp applied) followed by a blank space
2. If there's a character followed by blank space and then newline, replace it with character and blank space
3. If there's a character followed by a newline, replace it with character + blank space
4. If there's a character followed by two blank spaces and then a newline, replace it with character + blank space
5. If there's a dot at the end of the line, leave it like that cause it's a finishing dot.

As you can see, 2 and 3 are really similar, so I think the regexp could be something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]\n` but I don't know...first, if it's correct to search for a newline just adding \n and asecond, how to search for a blank space. After detecting the regexp, what follows I think it could be solved with a single `.Replace(Text,"regexp","regexp ")` where the ending blank space is from the form "char" + " "
So basically my question is, what could be the regexp for this patterns? 
In the 5th case, how can I search for the line terminator so it does not try to search for a newline after the last dot of a parragraph.
Can I use Chr(10) for newline and Chr(32) for space? 
Btw, I've been following these references:
[How to use RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)
[VBA Split strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17993389/vba-split-string-by-spaces)

Comment: It sounds like you're just trying to find text that ends in a newline and then removes the newline.

Comment: Almost, because spaces also matter. I have to improve the space the string uses but maintain readability cause it's a fixed paragraph

Comment: What if there's a dot or comma immediately followed by a newline?

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I haven't thought about that. It would be the same as 1st case, newline should be replaced with space

Comment: See if my answer fits your needs.

Comment: What do you mean by **character**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern will find any alphanumeric character, `.`, or `,` followed by optional whitespace and then a newline and replace it with the matched ending character, followed by one space.

```
Dim re
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "([\w.,])\s*\n"
strText = re.Replace(strText, "$1 ")
```

Output from testing. Ignore the brackets. They're just there to show spaces.

```
[the end.]     = [the end.]
[the end.\n]   = [the end. ]
[the end. \n]  = [the end. ]
[the end.  \n] = [the end. ]
[the end,]     = [the end,]
[the end,\n]   = [the end, ]
[the end, \n]  = [the end, ]
[the end,  \n] = [the end, ]
[the end]      = [the end]
[the end\n]    = [the end ]
[the end \n]   = [the end ]
[the end  \n]  = [the end ]
```

Comment: nit-picking:  `\w` also matches the underscore `_`  e.g: `\w` = `[A-Za-z0-9_]`  (in vbscript)

Comment: The line `strText = re.Replace(strText, "$1 ")` is replacing the patterno found directly in the text searched, right? And the `$1` is the result of the regexp processing?

Comment: @Kronos - The `$1` represents the first capture group (in this case, the ending character, `.`, or `,`). So it replaces the entire pattern found with just the ending character plus a space. Also, as @Ron mentioned, the `\w` includes the underscore character. If you don't want to count that, we'll need to use `[a-zA-Z0-9,.]` instead.

Comment: What to capture depends on what he meant by **character** in his original question.  Might be as simple as `(.)`  ;-).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - Yep. I made sure to specify _alphanumeric_ in my answer but I forgot about the `_`.

Comment: Also, of possible interest, is that in vbscript, characters that are not in that set are not matched.  So some foreign alphabet characters, and Unicode characters, would be excluded.

Comment: By character I mean any alphanumeric character, underscore included but it's little chance it have to be considered cause it's not used.

Comment: That worked! Thanks both. The implementation was easier this way

Comment: Sure, don't worry about it. Now I am trying to define my function to be called with a range of cells selected by the user. I tried giving it a range argument and trying to loop with a `For Each` every row within the column range  but it gives me an error. Do you know how to achieve this? I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168151/vba-pass-a-group-of-cells-as-range-to-function)